# i need to pass this files to WEKA classifiers by c++ code

Tags: c++, weka, system-calls

I'm writing a C++ project and created ARFF files within C++ code, so I need to pass these files to WEKA classifiers using C++.
I tried to use a system call but encountered errors.
I'm going to occasionally use a system call to WEKA to get some machine learning information. First I'd like to ensure that the training model (`training.model`) is up to date. So, at the beginning of `main()`, I call:

```
system("\"java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ML_data.arff -d training.model\"");
```

How can I call WEKA classifier from within C++ code?

Comment: Post the exact error that you receive when executing this code or the behavior you observe that makes you think you've encountered an error.

Comment: Did my suggestion resolve the issue? I'm really curious.

Comment: yes but still Linux gives me the error Error: Could not find or load main class weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic

Comment: OK I think I know what that is, see updated answer.

Comment: Any better now? Does setting classpath solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is with double quotes:

```
system("\"java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ML_data.arff -d training.model\"");
//      ^^                                                                 ^^
```

This piece of code should instead be as follows:

```
system("java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ML_data.arff -d training.model");
```

You appear to be using `\"` in order to pass the double quotes into the `system()` call, but that's excessive and causes an error. (The syntax for escaping a double quote is correct, but you don't need to pass the additional quotes to the `system()` function.)

Here's a minimal test case to show what happens on Linux with the syntax you have used:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
        system("\"ls -l\"");
}
```

Output:

> sh: ls -l: command not found

On the other hand, the code `system("ls -l");` correctly calls `ls -l` and displays the output in console.

**Edit:**

As far as your second error message goes:

> Error: Could not find or load main class weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic

It's a very common problem: [What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean). You need to set the classpath to point to `weka.jar` in your system, for example, like so (change the exact path to the one in your distribution):

```
system("java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ML_data.arff -d training.model");
```

or in the command line (note the use of the `export` command here)

> `export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/weka.jar:$CLASSPATH`
>
> `./name_of_your_cpp_executable_file`

or put `CLASSPATH` in your `~/.bashrc`:

> `CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/weka.jar:$CLASSPATH`
>
> `export CLASSPATH`